# Qt: different GUI on different machines

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtgui

I'm developing a Qt GUI application on Debian. It's run well on my machine (development environment) but on other environments (ex: testing, ...) the GUI is not correct as on my development environment.
This is the two example screenshot: [image]

Can you tell me why and how to fix this issue?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using [layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html)

Comment: The layouts didn't resolve my problem. I used property "sizePolicy (stretch)". This resolved my problem. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Put all labels and edit fields in a QGridLayout which will display it properly in a grid.

Example:

```
gridLayout = new QGridLayout(parent);
gridLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Secret key"), 0, 0); // row 0, column 0
gridLayout->addWidget(new QLineEdit, 0, 1); // row 0, column 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The layouts didn't resolve my problem. I used property "sizePolicy (stretch)". This resolved my problem. Thanks all!